# Splicing the wrong element(s)

Tags: arrays, loops, coffeescript, client-side-scripting

I have an array of `comments`. Some of these comments are actually subcomments of other nodes within `comments`. Every `comment` has a `num_comments`, `parent_id`, and `id` attribute. I know a comment has subcomments when itss number of comments is greater than 0.

I want to put the subcomments inside it's parent comment, and remove the subcomment from the array. After the outer for loop has completed, there should be no child comments inside the `comments` array, and each of the child comments is moved into it's parent comment's  `subcomments` array.

The issue is that after this code is run, every item in `comments` is deleted, and I get:

> Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

(Which is a result of `comments` being empty.)

Here's the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
    for comment in comments
        if comment.item.num_comments > 0
            comment.item.subcomments = [] unless comment.item.subcomments
            for comment_second in comments # Goes through a second time to find subcomments for the comment
                if comment_second.item.parent_id == comment.item.id
                    comment.item.subcomments.push(comment_second)
                    comments.splice(comments.indexOf(comment_second), 1)
```

**Edit:**

The answer below didn't work, but it was definitely a step in the right direction. I messed around with the code a bit, and what I think is happening is that `temp_comment.item.subcomment`s is not being defined as an array.
Which causes an error that doesn't let it get pushed. What this doesn't explain is nothing is being removed from the array.

```
    temp_comments = comments.slice(0)
    for comment in comments
      for comment_second in comments
        temp_comment = temp_comments[temp_comments.indexOf(comment)]
        temp_comment.item.subcomements = [] unless temp_comment.item.subcomments?
        if comment_second.item.parent_id == comment.item.id
          temp_comment.item.subcomments.push(comment_second)
          temp_comments.splice(temp_comments.indexOf(comment_second), 1)
    comments = temp_comments
```

I'm getting the same error message as before

2nd Edit:

The error is actually `[] is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

You have to be *very* careful when editing an array that you are looping through.  If you are on element `i`, and you remove it from the array, then now you are on what was previously element `i + 1`.  But then the loop increments and you've skipped what was originally element `i + 1`.  Here, you're in two nested loops, both over the list you're modifying, so the errors get much more complicated.

Here's some code that I believe does what you want.

```
temp_comments = comments.slice(0)
for comment in comments
  for comment_second in comments
    if comment_second.item.parent_id == comment.item.id
      comment.item.subcomments.push(comment_second)
      temp_comments.splice(temp_comments.indexOf(comment_second), 1)
comments = temp_comments
```

Here, we've created a temporary array (`comments.slice(0)` is a shallow copy idiom for arrays) and modified that instead of the original.

Edit: I'd assumed that the comment objects were set up for this.  To fix that, do this before the splicing:

```
for comment in comments
    comment.item.subcomments = []
```

Comment: @Jarred Do you have a line number on the error?  I suspect nothing is being removed because it errors and stops running before it finishes, so comments = temp_comments never happens.

Comment: @Jarred Are you sure?  There are no function calls on that line, so I'm pretty sure its not possible to get an `is not a function` error.

Answer (score 0):

You are still thinking in Javascript I think.

This should do the same thing and be more clear.

```
# Add subcomments to all comments that have them
for comment in comments when comment.item.num_comments > 0
  comment.item.subcomments = (sub for sub in comments when sub.item.parent_id == comment.item.id)

# Filter out comments that have parents
comments = (comment for comment in comments when !comment.item.parent_id)
```